# Event triggered on entering a textbox.

Tags: xcode

Is there any way of knowing when a text-box has been clicked on so that this can trigger an event? This may not be the best way to do it but I want to animate the text-box to a different part of the screen when it is clicked and then return to its original position when finished.

Comment: Xcode is the development system. What platform are you running your app on, iOS or OS X? What programming language? What have you tried?

Comment: I am new to all of this so please excuse my lack of knowledge here. I am developing it in Xcode 4.5 for an iPad. I assume that means it is iOS - is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question related to iOS, Set delegate for the UITextField, and in following delegaqte method, add your code.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Setting delegate [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't get anything to happen though. This is what I have:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't get anything to happen though. This is what I have: 
in the .h file 

@interface ObViewControllerMenu : UIViewController <UITextviewDelegate> 

in the .m file 

- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing (UITextView *) obsComment 

and then some code for a simple alert message to check it is firing. 

I know this must seem remarkably basic but new to this and tyring to get what delegates really are, how to use them and the correct syntax etc. 

Any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Did you use Interface builder(XIB) for the design?

Comment: Are you setting delegate like the pic i updated in my answer?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Sussed it. Very helpful indeed - much appreciated.